# Why is my CSS coding disabling my WordPress button?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm using Word Press with Mikado theme and have created a widget for a button the code for the button is in html. However, when I go to additional css under appearance and enter my css the link stops working. The html works (link wise) until I use the css. Any thoughts?

```css
.wp-block-button {
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0s;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0s;
}

.wp-block-button {
  background-color: transparent!important;
  border-color: transparent!important;
  color: #000000!important;
}

.wp-block-button:hover:before {
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.wp-block-button:before {
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: .1em;
  left: 2em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: 0s;
}

.wp-block-button:hover:before {
  width: 80% !important;
  transition: 0s;
}

.wp-block-button:before {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #59629a!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="wp-block-button has-custom-width wp-block-button__width-100 has-custom-font-size is-style-outline" style="font-size:18px">
  <a class="wp-block-button__link has-white-color has-text-color has-background wp-element-button" href="https://rothgrouplaw.com/new-client-intake-form/" style="border-radius:0px;background-color:#111e6e">Schedule Your Free Evaluation
        </a>
</div>
```

Comment: ok so I've discovered the link isn't broken it is just not positioned where the button is. What coding do I need to modify to get the link and button to line up?

Comment: if you mean the button is trapped "under" another element and you cant click it because the element on top is taking the space you could add `z-index: 99;` to the button and keep making the value of the `z-index` higher until its the top layer

Comment: I don't think that is the problem... it's like the link has some how become detached from the button and is hovering off to the side.

Comment: The :before pseudo element you added to the div, is laying on top of the link and blocking it from receiving any clicks. Give it a `background: red`, and you will clearly see it.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking out the `position: relative;` from the `.wp-block-button` class. I think that is your problem.